# Node JS crypto module troubling Express sessions

Tags: node.js, express

I started learning nodejs for web development a couple of days back. I am currently learning usage  of hash functions in nodejs crypto module. I came across the following problem

```
app.get('/hash',(req,res) =>{
let test = randomString.random(30);    //A module used to generate random strings

let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(test).digest('hex');

console.log(hash);                               //Statement-1

if (!(req.session.initialised))
{
  req.session.initialised = true;
  req.session.id = hash;
  console.log('Random: '+test);
  console.log('Session id: '+req.session.id);     //Statement-2
}
res.send("Hello")
})
```

I expected the logs from Statement-1 and Statement-2 to be same, but they are not.  I would like to know the reason for it. 
Prior Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. `id` is a session variable which I `can't change`. I should use a different name instead.